# Can a regex return a match that's not a part of the original string?

Tags: regex

I'm using an application that requires me to provide a regex for various files. It uses the matches from the regex to uniquely identify each file and then use a data store to retrieve metadata about these files.

there is however a problem with the application, so it assumes that the data which is used to identify each file is only numeric data. Hence, it stores the results of matches in integers.

I control the data store but not the names of the files. Since the application has a bug in it, I was hoping that I could use an encoding scheme to convert the non-numeric data to an integer. But for that I'd require the regex to return something that's not part of the original string as a match. Is this possible?

**Edit:** since my question was unclear. I'm not using a programming language. I'm just editing a configuration file. But the application is written in C++. I don't know what specific regex implementation they are using. But I guess it's not possible then.

The reason I asked the question is sql for example allows me to return something that's not part of any table. I was hoping there might be something similar with regex.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, sorry.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

No.  A regular expression will return the part(s) of the input string that match its pattern expression.  It will not perform any transformations or encodings, nor will it add stuff from elsewhere.

However, most languages and/or frameworks do support regex-based replacement.  In Javascript, for example, you can specify a callback function as replacement parameter.  The function will then be called for each match:

```
text = text.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, function (match) {
  return match.charCodeAt(0); // or whatever encoding you want to specify
});
```

But since you never told us what environment you're working in (programming language, development platform, OS) this might be totally irrelevant to you.  *(Hint: next time, do tell us a bit more).*

I’d say you probably need to write some extra code that will work on the matches found by your regular expression.